# I don't want to show popup for the button

Tags: javascript, html, popup

I have a button with the code below. When I click on this button it will show one popup which has a continue button that takes you to the next page. I want to go to the page directly without the popup showing when I click on the button.

How to make button not to show the popup when we click on it?

```
<a href="javascript:__doPostBack('btnContinuePhone','')" class="button-hpo blue-button-23" id="btnContinuePhone" onclick="javascript:return ConfirmModalPopUp('phone');"><span>Next</span></a>
```

Answer (score 4):

If you don't want the popup to show, then get rid of the onclick handler. I'm assuming the popup you're referring to is ConfirmModalPopUp.

This part

```
onclick="javascript:return ConfirmModalPopUp('phone');"
```

remove it.